# How to get list of failed Directories using Robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Good day,

Can't find a way how to get list of directories' names which were failed to copy with Robocopy.
Using below command:
robocopy C:\Temp P:\TEMP\ /FFT /E /R:0 /W:0 /ETA /NP /NFL /NJH /XD "System Volume Information" "$RECYCLE.BIN" /LOG:TEMP_LOG

And getting below summary:
QUOTE
8    C:\Temp
0    C:\Temp\Logs
2    C:\Temp\Logs\Defender
0    C:\Temp\Test\

---

```
           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Dirs :         4         0         3         0         1         0
```

Files :        10         0        10         0         0         0
Bytes :    78.9 k         0    78.9 k         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
Ended : Wednesday, December 22, 2021 10:24:02
UNQUOTE

One directory failed to copy. How can I get it's name?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Try/Catch` for external applications like `robocopy.exe`. You can rather use `$LASTEXITCODE` to do that. A sample is below:

```
robocopy b:\destinationdoesnotexist C:\documents /MIR

 if ($lastexitcode -eq 0)
 {
      write-host "Robocopy succeeded"
 }
else
{
      write-host "Robocopy failed with exit code:" $lastexitcode
}
```

Check the [List of Robocopy Exit Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/deploymentguys/robocopy-exit-codes)

Note: There is a `/log` parameter in the robocopy. Kindly use it for more insights.